# Permission problems, user in group but can read some files only

Tags: ubuntu, permissions

i have setted the owner, group , and mod to a folder and files inside. But, i can read some of them and some cannot. I have never seen this before.

```
rbackup@dul:~$ ls -l /home/Graficos/
total 252
drwxrwxr-x+ 12 jose jose 4096 nov 17 01:59 'Banco de Fotos (Solo Productos)'
drwxrwxr-x+ 43 jose jose 4096 mar 16  2020  Cafeteros
drwxrwxr-x+  4 jose jose 4096 ene 15 14:04  CIMES
drwxrwxr-x+  2 jose jose 4096 mar 16  2020 'Codigos 13 y 14'
drwxrwxr-x+  3 jose jose 4096 ene 15 15:51 'Corproacion del Bosque'
drwxrwxr-x+ 15 jose jose 4096 ene 15 16:23  Cremuccino
drwxrwxr-x+ 12 jose jose 4096 ene 15 15:04 'Della Tazza'
drwxrwxr-x+  8 jose jose 4096 ene 15 15:05  DLK
drwxrwxr-x+ 18 jose jose 4096 ene 15 15:55  Dulkre
drwxrwxr-x+ 11 jose jose 4096 ene 15 15:06 'Ever Cream'
drwxrwxr-x+  9 jose jose 4096 ene 15 15:07 'Ever Sweet'
drwxrwxr-x+ 11 jose jose 4096 mar 16  2020 'Fichas tecnicas y Carpetas de presentacion'
drwxrwxr-x+  5 jose jose 4096 mar 16  2020  Folletos
drwxrwxr-x+  5 jose jose 4096 nov 24 14:54 'Fotos Trabajo'
drwxrwxr-x+  6 jose jose 4096 nov 24 15:44  Fuentes
drwxrwxr-x+  5 jose jose 4096 mar 16  2020 'Golden Seed'
drwxrwxr-x+  3 jose jose 4096 mar 16  2020 'In The Cup'
drwxrwxr-x+  5 jose jose 4096 mar 16  2020  Krucor
drwxrwxr-x+ 11 jose jose 4096 ene 15 15:13  Logos
drwxrwxr-x+  9 jose jose 4096 ene 15 15:13 'Manjares del Sur'
drwxrwxr-x+  3 jose jose 4096 mar 16  2020  Marolio
drwxrwxr-x+  2 jose jose 4096 mar 16  2020  Mascaras
drwxrwxr-x+ 10 jose jose 4096 ene 15 16:14  Ordenar
drwxrwxr-x+  3 jose jose 4096 mar 16  2020  Panama
drwxrwxr-x+  2 jose jose 4096 mar 16  2020  Polimeros
drwxrwxr-x+  3 jose jose 4096 mar 16  2020  Publicidades
-rwxrwxr-x+  1 jose jose    0 ene 11 21:17  Readme.md
drwxrwxr-x+  8 jose jose 4096 nov 24 15:34  Renders
drwxrwxr-x+  8 jose jose 4096 ene 15 15:07  Salkré
drwxrwxr-x+  3 jose jose 4096 ene 15 15:07  Segafredo
drwxrwxr-x+  7 jose jose 4096 ene 15 15:10  Supermercados
drwxrwxr-x+  9 jose jose 4096 ene 15 16:11  Ubot
rbackup@dul:~$ ls -l /home/Graficos/CIMES
total 11340
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 jose jose 11588235 sep  5  2019 cimes3.pdf
drwxrwxr-x+ 2 jose jose     4096 ene 15 14:04 Etiqueta
drwxrwxr-x+ 4 jose jose     4096 ene 15 14:04 Folleto
rbackup@dul:~$ ls -l /home/Graficos/Fuentes
ls: cannot open directory '/home/Graficos/Fuentes': Permission denied
rbackup@dul:~$
```

i have absolutly no idea where to start...

i can read files with user "jose" , and can read all files with user "rbackup" if i change the owner to it.

```
jose@dul:/home/Graficos$ ls -l Fuentes/
total 3356
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 jose jose   4096 mar 16  2020 '__Back to Black Demo.ttf'
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 jose jose 102628 mar 16  2020 'Back to Black Demo.ttf'
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 jose jose  28928 mar 16  2020  BodoniStd.otf
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 jose jose 170861 mar 16  2020 'Book Antiqua Bold.ttf'
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 jose jose 121416 mar 16  2020 'book-antiqua_[allfont.es].ttf'
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 jose jose  52308 mar 16  2020  conduit_itc_bold.ttf
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 jose jose  54520 mar 16  2020  conduit_itc_light.ttf
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 jose jose  53700 mar 16  2020  conduit_itc_medium.ttf
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 jose jose 158992 mar 16  2020  DancingScript-Regular.ttf
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 jose jose 127472 mar 16  2020 'Gotham Bold.otf'
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 jose jose  29500 mar 16  2020 'Gotham Book Regular.otf'
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 jose jose 123400 mar 16  2020 'Gotham Condensed Bold.otf'
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 jose jose 131592 mar 16  2020 'Gotham Condensed Book.otf'
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 jose jose 128768 may 28  2020 'Gotham Medium.otf'
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 jose jose  64204 oct  9  2005 'Gotham-BoldItalic 2.ttf'
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 jose jose   4096 mar 16  2020  __Gotham-BoldItalic.otf
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 jose jose 102932 mar 16  2020  Gotham-BoldItalic.otf
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 jose jose   4096 mar 16  2020  __Gotham-Bold.otf
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 jose jose 127472 mar 16  2020  Gotham-Bold.otf
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 jose jose  66028 oct  9  2005  Gotham-Bold.ttf
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 jose jose  45744 jul 19  2016  GothamBold.ttf
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 jose jose   4096 mar 16  2020  __Gotham-BookIta.otf
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 jose jose 133304 mar 16  2020  Gotham-BookIta.otf
```

Comment: Does [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/396071/457018) answer your question?

Comment: Does `ls /home/Graficos/Fuentes` by itself work?

Comment: what do you mean? i can read folder "Fuentes" with user "jose" , strange thing is i setted all the permissions at the same time, so, if all folders have the same owner, group, and permissions, so, why can i read some of them and some of them not with specific user?

i have added some info in the FP

Comment: Yeah, but as rbackup, can you do `ls` without `-l` flag?

Comment: Also, look into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45161426/13020139). It may have something to do with your `+` setting at the end of each permissions listing.

Comment: i cannot with or without -l flag . Thought ACL was related only to samba . i am looking into this.

Comment: Did the ACL thing fix your issue?